# Write consistency = ALL: do I still need weekly repairs to avoid zombie records?

Tags: cassandra

As far as I understood, the problem of deleted data reappearing in Cassandra is as follows:

- A delete is issued with consistency < ALL (e.g. QUORUM)
- The delete succeeds, but some nodes in the replication set were not reachable during the delete
- A tombstone is written to all the reached nodes, nothing in the others
- 10 days pass, tombstone are eligible to be expired
- Compactions happen, tombstones are actually removed
- A read is issued: the nodes which received the delete reply with "no data"; the nodes which were unavailable during the delete reply with the old data; a zombie is produced

Now my question is: if the original delete was issued with consistency = ALL, all the nodes would either have the tombstone (before expiry&compaction) or no data at all (after expiry&compaction). No zombies should then be produced, even if we did not issue a repair before tombstone expiry.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you still need to run repairs even with CL.ALL on the delete if you want to guarantee no resurrected data. You just decrease likelihood of it occurring without you noticing it.

If a node is unavailable for the delete, the delete will fail for the client (because cl.all) but the other nodes all still received the delete. Even if your app will retry the delete theres a chance of it failing (ie your app's server hit by a meteor). So then you have a delete that has been seen by 2 of your 3 replicas. If you lowered your gc_grace and don't run repairs the other anti-entropy measures (hints, read repairs) may not ensure the tombstone (they are best effort not guarantee) was seen by the 3rd node before the tombstone is compacted away. The next read touches 3rd node which has the original data, and no tombstone exists to say it was deleted so you resurrect the data as its read repaired to other replicas.

What you can do is log a statement somewhere to point when there is a cl.all timeout or failure. This is not a guarantee since your app can die before the log, and a failure does not actually mean that the write did not get to all replicas - just that it *may* of failed to write.  That said I would strongly recommend just using quorum (or local_quorum). That way you can have some host failures without losing availability since you need the repairs for the guarantee anyway.

Comment: I would not consider this situation as a "resurrection", since the delete has never been acknowledged. Anyway you raise a very interesting point I had never thought about: a failed insert/update/delete on Cassandra does not guarantee that the data has not actually been written.

Answer (score 1):

When issuing queries with Consistency=ALL, every node having the token range of that particular record has to acknowledge. So if one of the NODE was down during this process, the DELETE will fail as it can't achieve the required consistency=ALL.

So consistency=ALL, might end up being a scenario where every node in the cluster has to stay up otherwise queries will fail. That's why people recommend to use lesser stronger consistency like QUORUM. So you are sacrificing high availability for REPAIRs if you want to perform queries at CONSISTENCY=ALL

Comment: Well yes unfortunately I'm stuck with a Cassandra cluster with 2 (two) nodes, so it does not really make a difference!